# FirebaseMessaging.h file not found while archive

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I recently integrated pushNotification through FireBase, Everything works fine in my project and I successfully integrated in my project and able to get pushNotificiation but while I archive my project to submit in store I got a error FirebaseMessaging.h file not found , I installed firebase through pods. How to fix this issue I have referred following answers but nothing helps me.                          [enter link description here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2233)

Comment: `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`

Comment: I have tried this but this didnt help .

Comment: If you have an old CocoaPods version, try updating.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing kind of the same issue, I have solved it by clearing CocoaPods cache and redownloading it. For details, follow this - stackoverflow.com/a/76538225/7728628